# Left join to a subquery where Row_Number = 1

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, left-join, window-functions, row-number

I'm so stupid! What's the best way to handle the scenario below? ID 27 doesn't exist in SuperRadSubQuery, but it does exist in WayCoolLeftTable. If I run this entire query it doesn't return anything. If I exclude the AND on the last line it returns one row. This is definitely not what I expected and I'm surprised that my WHERE filter is "corrupting" my LEFT JOIN. I'd prefer to not use a temp table. I could MAX instead, but is that stupid too? Thanks in advance!

```
SELECT *
    FROM WayCoolLeftTable a
    LEFT JOIN
                (
                    SELECT   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY SourceDate DESC) AS RowNumber
                            ,ID
                            ,SourceDate
                    FROM SuperRadSubQuery
                ) b
            ON a.ID = b.ID
WHERE a.ID = 27
AND b.RowNumber = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

The condition on the second table goes in the `on` clause:

```
SELECT *
FROM WayCoolLeftTable a LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY SourceDate DESC) AS RowNumber,
            ID, SourceDate
      FROM SuperRadSubQuery
     ) b
     ON a.ID = b.ID and b.RowNumber = 1
WHERE a.ID = 27;
```

Otherwise, the outer join turns into an `inner join`.

SQL Server offers a more efficient way to do this, using lateral joins.  The code looks like:

```
SELECT *
FROM WayCoolLeftTable a OUTER APPLY
     (SELECT *  -- or whatever columns you want
      FROM SuperRadSubQuery
      WHERE a.ID = b.ID
      ORDER BY SourceDate DESC
     ) b
WHERE a.ID = 27;
```

Comment: I guess that the example with OUTER APPLY is not equivalent because it is not constrained to returning only the first row